# How to display a pdf file inside jsp page from a local machine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, pdf

I have to show a .pdf file inside a jsp page onload. The generated pdf is located inside /tmp of the local machine. 
Please Help .

Answer (score 0):

```
<object data="/tmp/filename.pdf" type="application/pdf">
         <embed src="/tmp/filename.pdf" type="application/pdf" /> 
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use iFrame to display pdf inside a page as well.

Comment: I have already use iFrame but inside iFrame it doesn't open pdf.

Comment: Be sure that you already installed pdf reader addon in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a JSP . JSPs are solely inteneded to render character response data. Anything else, be it PDF, images  or any other binary stream, must be emitted with a servlet.

create servlet file.
for example 
`setContentType(application/excel);` but I think it depends on your browser.

also for pdf  file `setContentType(application/pdf);`